# Prevent helm from temporarily unsplitting windows

Tags: helm

If I have a frame split vertically with a dedicated buffer in the top window and the lower window selected I would like to be able to invoke a helm command without helm temporarily unsplitting the frame / hiding the upper window.

Desired behavior:

```
 +----------------------+    +----------------------+  
 |  Dedicated window    |    |  Dedicated window    |
 +----------------------+    +----------------------+
 |                      |    |                      |
 |                      |    |  "Selected" window   |
 |  Selected window     |    |                      |
 |                      | => |                      |
 |                      |    +----------------------+
 |                      |    |                      |
 |                      |    |  Helm completions    |
 |                      |    |                      |
 |                      |    |                      |
 |                      |    |                      |
 +----------------------+    +----------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following:

```el
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("\\`\\*helm"
               (display-buffer-in-side-window)
               (window-height . 0.4)))

(setq helm-display-function #'display-buffer)
```